# Vertical Center A Div Accounting For A fixed Bar Up Top

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a logo that needs to be vertically centered. I was able to center it with flexbox method using display flex on the parent and margin auto on the child.

BUT, I have a fixed top bar with a height of 150px overlapping the parent container. So the logo is now 150px off from being vertically centered.

What's the best way to solve this other than adding padding-top on the image?

```css
    h1, p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    background: green;
    }
    .top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background: tomato;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .logo {
    margin: auto;
    }
    .section{
    height: 1500px;
    background: pink;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
      <div class="top-bar">
       <h1>Top Bar</h1>
      </div>
       <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>

    <div class="section">
      <p>Section</p>
   </div>
```

Code: https://codepen.io/drunktuts/full/oemRxp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `padding-top` to the `header`, which will make the `logo` centered between the bottom of the `top-bar` and the viewports bottom.

Additionally you also need to change it height as well, to `min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);`, or add `box-sizing: border-box` (used in the codepen) so the padding gets included in the set height.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzgOGV)

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
h1, p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
  padding-top: 150px;
}
.top-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo {
  margin: auto;
}
.section{
  height: 1500px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="top-bar">
    <h1>Top Bar</h1>
  </div>
  <img class="logo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
<div class="section">
  <p>Section</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @ChrisBrennan I assume you upvoted, though I can't see it is accepted. Did you click the gray check mark at the top left corner of my answer? ... It will turn green when selected.

Comment: I clicked the check mark just now. Wow, that's really easy to miss.

Comment: It might be a good idea to put an animation effect on the check mark while it's grayed out.

Comment: @ChrisBrennan Thanks...will pass that idea forwards next time I put something on Meta.